# The type arguments for method JsonHelper.FromJson<T>(string) cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this class.

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
        return wrapper.Items;
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array, bool prettyPrint)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper, prettyPrint);
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] Items;
    }


}
```

I called one of the methods from the call as

```
SqliteDatabase sqlDB = new SqliteDatabase (dbPath);
var result = sqlDB.ExecuteQuery ("SELECT * FROM CurrentClub WHERE id = 2");
var row = result.Rows [0];
List<Vector3> BLEBridge.club3Dpts = JsonHelper.FromJson(row ["Club3DPoints"].ToString ());
```

I have error as

```
error CS0411: The type arguments for method `JsonHelper.FromJson<T>(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
```

Even I changed to

```
List<Vector3> BLEBridge.club3Dpts = JsonHelper.FromJson("");
```

I have the same error.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You need to specify the generic type, e.g. `JsonHelper.FromJson<List<Vector3>>(row ["Club3DPoints"].ToString())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to specify the type `T` like below and that's what it's complaining about

```
 Vector3[] BLEBridge.club3Dpts = JsonHelper.FromJson<Vector3>(row ["Club3DPoints"].ToString ());
```

See your method signature `T[] FromJson<T>(string json)` since you are trying to map to `List<Vector3>` you should specify type `Vector3`